# Facing problem in running this Python code

Tags: python, package

I am very new to Python. After installing a package cosmoTransitions I have to run a code and there are some example programs and I have already tried one and getting the below mentioned error but can't understand where the error comes from

```
def approxZeroTMin(self):
    # There are generically two minima at zero temperature in this model,
    # and we want to include both of them.
    v = v2**.5
    return [np.array([v,v,v]), np.array([v,v,v])]


def makePlots(m=None):
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
if m is None:
    m = model1()
    m.findAllTransitions()
# --
plt.figure()
m.plotPhasesPhi()
plt.axis([0,300,-50,550])
plt.title("Minima as a function of temperature")
plt.show()
# --
plt.figure(figsize=(8,3))
ax = plt.subplot(131)
T = 0
m.plot2d((-450,450,-450,450), T=T, cfrac=.4,clevs=65,n=100,lw=.5)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.set_title("$T = %0.2f$" % T)
ax.set_xlabel(R"$\phi_1$")
ax.set_ylabel(R"$\phi_2$")
ax = plt.subplot(132)
T = m.TnTrans[1]['Tnuc']
instanton = m.TnTrans[1]['instanton']
phi = instanton.Phi
m.plot2d((-450,450,-450,450), T=T, cfrac=.4,clevs=65,n=100,lw=.5)
ax.plot(phi[:,0], phi[:,1], 'k')
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.set_title("$T = %0.2f$" % T)
ax.set_yticklabels([])
ax.set_xlabel(R"$\phi_1$")
ax = plt.subplot(133)
T = m.TnTrans[0]['Tnuc']
m.plot2d((-450,450,-450,450), T=T, cfrac=.4,clevs=65,n=100,lw=.5)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.set_title("$T = %0.2f$" % T)
ax.set_yticklabels([])
ax.set_xlabel(R"$\phi_1$")
# --
plt.figure()
plt.plot(instanton.profile1D.R, instanton.profile1D.Phi)
plt.xlabel("radius")
plt.ylabel(R"$\phi-\phi_{min}$ (along the path)")
plt.title("Tunneling profile")
```

But after running this it showing too many errors and i can't also distinguish them where they came from. 
This is the error messege:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/SATYABRATA/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32  /sdd.py", line 2, in <module>
from cosmoTransitions import generic_potential
File "C:\Users\SATYABRATA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32    \lib\site-packages\cosmoTransitions\generic_potential.py", line 20, in <module>
from .finiteT import Jb_spline as Jb
File "C:\Users\SATYABRATA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\cosmoTransitions\finiteT.py", line 25, in <module>
from scipy.misc import factorial as fac
ImportError: cannot import name 'factorial' from 'scipy.misc' (C:\Users     \SATYABRATA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\misc\__init__.py)
```

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Do you have scipy installed?

Comment: Yes scipy, numpy, matplotlib,cosmoTransitions all installed

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.1.0/reference/generated/scipy.misc.factorial.html says scipy.misc.factorial is depricated.  If you already have the latest version of cosmoTransitions (maybe try to find dev version), you could try to replace scipy with an older version.  Or try to change the source to replace the call to scipy.misc.factorial with scipy.special.factorial

Comment: Try `from scipy.special import factorial` in the shell if it works, change that line in `finiteT.py` and give feedback to the maintainers.

Comment: After upadating scipy and numpy I am facing the same problem

Comment: Thank you very much @wwii you are right

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In a python shell try

```
from scipy.special import factorial
```

If you don't get an ImportError, open `finiteT.py` in your editor (filepath from the error message you posted):

```
"C:\Users\SATYABRATA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\cosmoTransitions\finiteT.py"
```

On line 25 change

```
from scipy.misc import factorial as fac
```

to

```
from scipy.special import factorial as fac
```

or

```
try: 
    from scipy.misc import factorial as fac 
except ImportError: 
    from scipy.special import factorial as fac
```

There haven't been any commits to that repository since Feb,2018 - so you might as well change your copy.

Comment: Was that you? I didn't check. Gj.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of cosmoTransition package, there is this line `from scipy.misc import factorial as fac` which is causing the issue. Your scipy version is probably higher than 1.0.0. Because they deprecated this. You should try to downgrade the scipy version to 1.0.0 by using this: `python3 -m pip install scipy==1.0 --upgrade`. Also, from what I understand [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56284155/10183880), you can also try to use 1.2

Comment: It is actually in scipy.special. --> `from scipy.special import factorial`

Comment: Yes you are right but it is stated as deprecated in the scipy documentation page. So...

Comment: The actual statement in [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.1.0/reference/generated/scipy.misc.factorial.html) is that importing from `scipy.misc` is deprecated (not the function itself) and to import from `scipy.special`.